# Airflow - Async pod lauch

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine

we have a long-running task in airflow (5hr and more)

I'm looking on a way to do *fire a forget* (after the pod started running) and monitor the status of the task using a sensor
The rationale is to free the worker and reduce resource consumption.

This line seems to monitor for pod health.
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/10ce31127f1ff87176158935925afce46a989917/airflow/kubernetes/pod_launcher.py#L140

Now, I know I can override this limitation using a Cloud Function to trigger the pod, but this is a kind of over-complication of the DAG.

I've also opened an issue in [github](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10791)

Comment: Haven't used Airflow on K8 but did you check this [`run_pod_async`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/10ce31127f1ff87176158935925afce46a989917/airflow/kubernetes/pod_launcher.py#L68) method?

Comment: it is used this method internally (https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/a0374a5f95d5b4870cd86b0832a29b9f134ec8b7/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod.py#L425)
but still the code use monitor_pod to wait for it completion

Comment: Are you using Cloud Composer?

Comment: Yes. I'm using composer with